# C++ Using GMP to work with big numbers, decimals, and integers

Tags: c++, gmp

How would I use GMP to do something like this:

I have two integers, a and b, and I want to plug them into the formula:
answer=(a^3 +2*a^2*b-6a+b+7)/(3a^2+b^2-5)

Then I need to check if "answer" is an integer for big values of a and b.

So it will look like this, but I don't know how to do it with GMP:

```
    for (a=2; a<1000000; a=a+1)
    {
         for (b=1; b<1000000; b=b+1)
         {
           answer=(a^3 +2*a^2*b-6a+b+7)/(3a^2+b^2-5);
           if (floor(answer)==answer && a>b)
           {
             cout<<endl<<setw(50)<<a<<setw(50)<<b<<setw(50)<<answer<<endl;
           }
         }
    }
```

So answer may end up being something like: 258658.000000000000000002523655  which is not an integer, so I need to distinguish that from an integer, say: 258658

Thanks!

Comment: You might start here: http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Functions.html#Integer-Functions  Regardless of the mechanism, you can make use of the identity `b * floor(a/b) = a` if and only if `a/b` is an integer.

Comment: More simply, test if `numerator%denominator` is zero. With gmpxx, use `a*a*a`, not `a^3`.